# Manually call a rust dynamic library

Tags: rust, dynamic-library

I'm currently playing around with [`DynamicLibrary`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/dynamic_lib/struct.DynamicLibrary.html).

The code of my dynamic library (compiled with `rustc --crate-type dylib dylib.rs`):

```
// dylib.rs
#[no_mangle]
pub fn minicall() -> u8 {
    3u8
}
```

And the code to call it:

```
// caller.rs
use std::dynamic_lib::DynamicLibrary;

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();

    DynamicLibrary::prepend_search_path(&::std::os::getcwd());

    match DynamicLibrary::open(Some("./libdylib.so")) {
        Err(e) => panic!("ERROR: {}", e),
        Ok(lib) => {
            println!("Unsafe bloc !");
            let func = unsafe {
                match lib.symbol::< fn() -> u8 >("minicall") {
                        Err(e) => { panic!("ERROR: {}", e) },
                        Ok(f) => { *f },
                }
            };
            println!("call func !");
            let new_value = func();

            println!("extend vec !");
            v.push(new_value);
        }
    }

    println!("v is: {}", v);
}
```

I have this output :

```
~> ./caller 
Unsafe bloc !
call func !
Illegal instruction
```

And here I'm quite lost. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is how the `symbol` function works. It has signature:

```
unsafe fn symbol<T>(&self, symbol: &str) -> Result<*mut T, String>
```

A loaded library is basically a big array in memory with certain addresses labelled with a name (the symbol names). Querying for a symbol looks up the address and returns a pointer straight to it. A function in a library is a long sequence of instructions, so querying for a function's name returns a (function) pointer directly to the start. This can then be called as a normal function pointer. The Rust `DynamicLibrary` API is returning this pointer, that is, `*mut T` points directly to the chunk of memory in the dynamic library (which is supposedly/hopefully of type `T`).

The type `fn(...) -> ...` is a function pointer itself, that is, it is 8 bytes (or 4 bytes) storing the address of the start of the function it represents. Hence, calling `lib.symbol::< fn() -> u8 >("minicall")` is saying "find me the address of the thing called `minicall` (which is a *pointer to a function*)", it is not saying "find me the address of the thing called `minicall` (which is a function)". The return value of `*mut (fn() -> u8)` is then doubly-indirect, and dereferencing it to call it is interpreting the first 8 (or 4) bytes of the function code as a pointer (i.e. random machine instructions/function prelude), it is not executing them.

(Side-note: it would probably work if you had `#[no_mangle] pub static minicall: fn() -> u8 = the_real_minicall;` in your library, but you probably don't want this.)

The call to `lib.symbol::<T>("minicall")` is returning the exact function pointer we want (that is, it is returning a pointer to the start of the code of `minicall`), so it just becomes a question of expressing this to the compiler. Unfortunately, there is currently no type `T` that makes `*mut T` a function pointer, so one must first set `T = u8` (i.e. `lib.symbol::<u8>("minicall")`) and then cast the return value to the appropriate function pointer type via `transmute::<_, fn() -> u8>(pointer)`.

(I'm answering this even after the other answer was accepted because I don't think it explained the cause very well, just gave the solution.)

---

Last thing, this isn't a problem in this case, but it trips people a lot: the Rust ABI (the calling convention used for functions of type `fn(...) -> ...`) is not the same as the C ABI, so functions loaded from C dynamic libraries should be given type `extern "C" fn(...) -> ...`, *not* `fn(...) -> ...`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem stems from the fact that you are casting between incompatible types. Specifically, the dereference `*f` is going to point to the wrong place. I looked in the Rust code to see how the library is supposed to be used and found an example in `src/librustc/plugin/load.rs`. I adapted that code to your example:

```
let func = unsafe {
    // Let this return a `*mut u8`, a very generic pointer
    match lib.symbol("minicall") {
        Err(e) => { fail!("ERROR: {}", e) },
        // And then cast that pointer a function
        Ok(f) => { std::mem::transmute::<*mut u8, fn() -> u8>(f) },
    }
};
println!("call func !");
let new_value = func();
```

The output:

```
$ ./caller
Unsafe bloc !
call func !
extend vec !
v is: [3]
```

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. The documentation isn't clear about this at all.

Comment: That's very charitable; there aren't really any docs at the moment... I even saw `#![allow(missing_docs)]` while source-diving ^_^.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question/answer, the `std::dynamic_lib` API seems to have gone away. As of this writing it looks like [libloading](https://github.com/nagisa/rust_libloading/) is the most popular way of dynamically loading libraries on crates.io.